# How random sign matrix works in compression algorithm

Tags: matrices, projection, random-matrices, compression

The [video](https://vimeo.com/287812139) introduce a compression algorithm in 6:15s,

The compression algorithm stated as below

> For a weight matrix A,
>
> 1. generate $k$ random sign matrices $M_1,...,M_k$
> 2. return $\hat{A}=\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_{t=1}<A, M_t> M_t$

And the result $\hat{A}$ reduced number of parameters to $k$

I fail to understand how the compression is done here. Any suggestion?

Comment: In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05296.pdf) see prop 3.1 where it says _"The above proposition suggests that if a vector x is aligned to a matrix M (i.e. correlated with high singular directions of M), then matrix M becomes less sensitive to noise at x..."_ I'm no expert but I think the random sign matrices are there to produce a new matrix that has these high singular directions, so that 2) is like random projections dimensionality reduction onto the $M_t$. The hope is later layers are less sensitive to noise caused by rounding / truncation of weights in this layer (see appendix A.2)

Comment: ^ the general thrust of the paper seems to be that you can make the net's matrices more stable to noise this way, and this allows you to get away with truncating / rounding weights / cutting connections / exploiting sparsity in the network etc. without adversely affecting deeper layers.

Comment: @flinty Thank you for your detailed answer. It's just that I don't understand the operation here. If $<A, M_t>$ is the random projection then why we want extra $M_t$? Also, why take the average of $k$ here?

Comment: The bit in the sum is just how projection / change of basis works. . The division by $k$ is just normalizing it. $\hat{A}$ is a linear combination of some random sign matrices. The coefficients of the combination are determined by the part in the angle brackets, a scalar I think - the correlation between $A$ and $M_t$

Comment: @flinty I have done some searching, but I still have no clue on the operation. Could you provide some link for reference? I understand that the last equation equals to$\frac{1}{k}\sum^k_tM_t^TAM^t$.

Comment: @flinty According to proposition 3.1, higher correlated signular value between weight matrix $A$ and $x$ will result in less noise sensitivity. The aim of the compression is to select the top $k$ singular value?